# PUT k8s deployment returns 404

Tags: kubernetes

According to the `Replacement` section of [Kubernetes API reference v1.24](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.24/#deployment-v1-apps) I should be able to **create** a deployment with a `PUT /apis/apps/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/deployments/{name}` HTTP request. The success response here is `201 Created`. However, when I try the following, I get a `404 Not Found` which is of course correct but unwanted: PUT requests should be treated as Create statements if the resource does not yet exist [as documented](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/#api-verbs). Updating a deployment does work (and returns the expected `200 OK` HTTP response). Is there any documentation regarding this? Or is the request somehow incorrect? Ty.

```
➜  ~ curl --request PUT \
  --url http://localhost:8080/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/ns/deployments/nginx-deployment \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --data '{
        "apiVersion":"apps/v1",
        "kind":"Deployment",
        "metadata":{
                "name":"nginx-deployment",
                "labels":{
                        "app":"nginx"
                }
        },
        "spec": {
        "replicas" : 3,
        "selector": {
                "matchLabels" : {
                        "app":"nginx"
                }
        },
        "template" : {
        "metadata" : {
                "labels" : {
                        "app":"nginx"
                }
        },
        "spec":{
                "containers":[
                        {
                                "name":"ngnix",
                                "image":"nginx:1.7.9",
                                "ports":[
                                  {
                                    "containerPort": 80
                            }
                                ]
                        }
                ]
        }
 }
}
}'
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "deployments.apps \"nginx-deployment\" not found",
  "reason": "NotFound",
  "details": {
    "name": "nginx-deployment",
    "group": "apps",
    "kind": "deployments"
  },
  "code": 404
}%
```

Comment: Does the namespace `ns` exist?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you provided,

```
PUT /apis/apps/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/deployments/{name}
```

is meant to "replace the specified Deployment", while a Deployment is created with a POST:

```
create a Deployment

HTTP Request

POST /apis/apps/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/deployments
```

You are correct that the documentation also states:

> For PUT requests, Kubernetes internally classifies these as either create or update based on the state of the existing object

so there seems to be a contradiction, but the Deployment API spec states that POST should be used to create a deployment and PUT to update it.